# GeoJSON vector data tiles disappear

Tags: openlayers, cesium

I found an example of how to show GeoJSON data on cesium and I followed that example

The data is displaying but tiles are disappearing when I zoom in more and more

I tried with same with us sample data same this the data displays but when zoom in tiles are disappearing

Here is the example what I used

```
 https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html?src=GeoJSON%2520and%2520TopoJSON.html
```

Here is how my data appears

image.png

image.png

I am using reactJS

Here is my code

```
        this.state.Viewer.dataSources.add(this.state.Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('data/adu_governorate..geojson', {
                stroke: this.state.Cesium.Color.HOTPINK,
                fill: this.state.Cesium.Color.PINK.withAlpha(0.5),
                strokeWidth: 3
            }));
```

Comment: your image links failed